# docker-compose up error, Invalid address

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to use elastic's docker-elk,  then I cloned elastic github code. And I want to use a specific ip for every container, so I define a specific ip for every container, when I run `docker-compose up`, I meet the error

```
ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: Invalid address 172.18.1.3: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

it shows no any of network's subnet, but I define the subnet, and `docker-compose.yml` like this

```
version: '2'

services:

  elasticsearch:
    build: elasticsearch/      
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      elk:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.3

  logstash:
    build: logstash/
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      elk:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.4
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build: kibana/
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      elk:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.5
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:

  elk:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.18.1.0/24
```

and `docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:20:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:21:56 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Comment: Post the output of `docker version`

Answer (score 23):

I just ran into this issue and my issue seems to be issues with how docker caches networks and containers. I had to `docker network rm` the network that was previously created. I also had to `docker ps -a` and `docker rm` the previously created containers as they're cached to use the network that you'll be removing. After I removed all those leftover artifacts, it started up correctly.

Comment: @Isuru Dilshan solution is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68028426/4632019

Answer (score 11):

Use `docker-compose down` and try to run `docker-compose up`. This works with me

Answer (score 2):

Beside removing network(s) that is/are in conflicting subnet IP with `docker network rm <networkname>` command. 
Make sure that you double check all IP addresses assigned to services in your **docker compose file**, against subnet IP(s) specified in **networks** section of the same docker compose file. It is easy to overlook IP when your docker composer file has many services and networks.

Example of wrong subnet error: **"172.22.0.1: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets"**.

```
version: '3'

services:
  web_service:
    networks:
      webservices:
        ipv4_address: 172.22.0.1
    image: nginx:latest
    environment:
     - NGINX_HOST=web.phenex.docker
     - NGINX_PORT=80

networks:
  webservices:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.21.0.0/24
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Compose [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address), the `ipam` block must have subnet range and gateway defined. So just update yours to:

```
ipam:
  config:        
    - driver: default
      subnet: 172.18.1.0/24
      gateway: 172.18.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to use elastic's docker-elk, then I cloned elastic github code. And I want to use a specific ip for every container, so I define a specific ip for every container, when I run docker-compose up, I meet the error

ERROR: for elasticsearch  Cannot start service elasticsearch: Invalid address 172.18.1.3: It does not belong to any of this network's subnets
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

ERROR OBJECT & CODES
An Error object will be returned for any error encountered. For example:

```
{
    "error": {
        "error_code": 10001,
        "error_message": "Invalid IP address."
    }
```

Comment: (You almost never need to know or set the container-private IP addresses.  I'd suggest deleting _all_ of the `networks:` blocks shown in the question, and using the `default` network Compose provides along with the default Docker-assigned IP addresses.)